# Adding duplicate element inside an XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have this XML file:

```
<root>
  <Friend_2>
    <MESSAGE_BODY>hi</MESSAGE_BODY>
    <MESSAGE_SENDER_ID>1</MESSAGE_SENDER_ID>
    <MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID>2</MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID>
    <MESSAGE_CREATION_DATE>2014-08-29T15:33:18.1191004+03:00</MESSAGE_CREATION_DATE>
  </Friend_2>
</root>
```

I am using this function to add elements to this file by doing this :

```
private void createNode(string body, string senderid, string receiverid,DateTime creationDate,string path1,string path2)
{
    XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(path1);
    XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(path2);
    XElement root1 = new XElement("Friend_"+receiverid);
    XElement root2 = new XElement("Friend_"+senderid);

    root1.Add(new XElement("MESSAGE_BODY", body));
    root1.Add(new XElement("MESSAGE_SENDER_ID", senderid));
    root1.Add(new XElement("MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID", receiverid));
    root1.Add(new XElement("MESSAGE_CREATION_DATE", creationDate));


    root2.Add(new XElement("MESSAGE_BODY", body));
    root2.Add(new XElement("MESSAGE_SENDER_ID", senderid));
    root2.Add(new XElement("MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID", receiverid));
    root2.Add(new XElement("MESSAGE_CREATION_DATE", creationDate));

    if (doc1.Root.Element(root1.Name.LocalName) == null)
    {
        doc1.Element("root").Add(root1);
    }

    if (doc2.Root.Element(root2.Name.LocalName) == null)
    {
        doc2.Element("root").Add(root2);
    }

    doc1.Save(path1);
    doc2.Save(path2);
}
```

But the original elements are being replaced. I want my XML file to look like this:

```
<root>
  <Friend_2>
    <MESSAGE_BODY>hi</MESSAGE_BODY>
    <MESSAGE_SENDER_ID>1</MESSAGE_SENDER_ID>
    <MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID>2</MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID>
    <MESSAGE_CREATION_DATE>2014-08-29T15:33:18.1191004+03:00</MESSAGE_CREATION_DATE>
    <MESSAGE_BODY>how r you ?</MESSAGE_BODY>
    <MESSAGE_SENDER_ID>1</MESSAGE_SENDER_ID>
    <MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID>2</MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID>
    <MESSAGE_CREATION_DATE>2014-10-29T15:33:18.1191004+03:00</MESSAGE_CREATION_DATE>
  </Friend_2>
</root>
```

My main reason to have this schema is because I am using a function that parses the document and returns a dataTable containing 4 columns and 2 rows

```
public static DataSet ConvertXMLToDataTable(string xmlString)
{
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    dataset.ReadXml(xmlString);
    return dataset.Tables.Count > 0 ? dataset : null;
}

DataSet Chat_ds=Convertor.ConvertXMLToDataTable(path);
            if (Chat_ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                DataTable Chat_dt = Chat_ds.Tables["Friend_" + FriendID];

...................
```

I can't have my xml to look like this :

```
  <root>
    <Friend_2>
    <message>
    <MESSAGE_BODY>hi</MESSAGE_BODY>
    <MESSAGE_SENDER_ID>1</MESSAGE_SENDER_ID>
    <MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID>2</MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID>
    <MESSAGE_CREATION_DATE>2014-08-29T15:33:18.1191004+03:00</MESSAGE_CREATION_DATE>
     </message>

    <message>
    <MESSAGE_BODY>how r you ?</MESSAGE_BODY>
    <MESSAGE_SENDER_ID>1</MESSAGE_SENDER_ID>
    <MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID>2</MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID>
    <MESSAGE_CREATION_DATE>2014-10-29T15:33:18.1191004+03:00</MESSAGE_CREATION_DATE>
     </message>

     </Friend_2>
     </root>
```

Comment: IF I understand, you're actually re-creating your Friend_2 node, so yeah, I would expect its content to be "replaced".

Comment: how would i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider doing some check for your `Friend_n` nodes' existence. For now, you're just creating a completely new `Friend_n` node, so the old content doesn't exist anymore.

```
private void createNode(string body, string senderid, string receiverid,DateTime creationDate,string path1,string path2)
{
    XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(path1);
    XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(path2);

    string receiver = "Friend_"+receiverid;
    string sender = "Friend_"+senderid;
    XElement root1 = doc1.Element(receiver);
    if (root1 == null)
    {
        root1 = new XElement(receiver);
        doc1.Root.Add(root1);
    }
    XElement root2 = doc1.Element(sender);
    if (root2 == null)
    {
        root2 = new XElement(sender);
        doc2.Root.Add(root2);
    }

    root1.Add(new XElement("MESSAGE_BODY", body));
    root1.Add(new XElement("MESSAGE_SENDER_ID", senderid));
    root1.Add(new XElement("MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID", receiverid));
    root1.Add(new XElement("MESSAGE_CREATION_DATE", creationDate));

    root2.Add(new XElement("MESSAGE_BODY", body));
    root2.Add(new XElement("MESSAGE_SENDER_ID", senderid));
    root2.Add(new XElement("MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID", receiverid));
    root2.Add(new XElement("MESSAGE_CREATION_DATE", creationDate));

    doc1.Save(path1);
    doc2.Save(path2);
}
```

Comment: Note: this is mostly done by memory, so it may not work out of the box. I will try to fix if it's the case, but the important part is the check at start.

Comment: i am having an exception `This operation would create an incorrectly structured document` on this line `doc1.Add(root1);`

Comment: i replaced it by : `doc1.Root.Add(root1)`  and everything is ok now